# What does a plant suffering from a gas leak look like?

Tags: wilt, poisons, air-flow

What does a plant suffering from a gas leak look like?

When I look this up, I often see peace lily's but they perk up within hours after wilting from watering sufficiently. Are there any visible or characteristic signs, such as a certain kind of browning?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "gas" and "leak" ? Assuming by "leak" you mean in your home. If you mean natural gas ( from gas distribution system , methane ) in the atmosphere , not much . It is essential inert to the plant in small quantities. It contains mercaptan (anywhere in the civilized world ) and has a distinct odor which you will smell long before there is any possible affect on a plant. Unlikely you mean natural gas in soil; That causes wilting in plants and is a marker used by gas pipelines to find pinhole pipe leaks in agricultural areas. My guess ,you are over or under watering your plant ( and probably there are no zebras around).

Comment: Well, there is definitely that odor. In your link, how much gas leak in a home does it take for a plan to wilt like that?

Comment: @ina, if you smell gas in your home please call help immediately. The gas is not only toxic but also highly explosive.

Comment: You will get a headache and an explosion long before a plant will have a problem.

Comment: well, the explosion does not happen until it hits 15% or so. a small gas leak is like less than 5%. headache yes. they tried to fix it multiple times but i think it just keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

Plants seem to die when there is a gas leak, even before you smell anything. Look [here](https://connect2local.com/l/207239/c/673347/3-signs-you-need-gas-line-repair) for more information. Important indication of a gas leak is that all plants seem to suffer, not just one. Good luck.

Comment: That link is incorrect nonsense. The human nose can detect odorant thiols (mercaptans) in the parts-per-billion range; they are some of the smelliest substances on the planet. In most circumstances (like, unless the plant was away from human habitation) you would smell an odorized gas leak long before the plant wilted and died. Now, if you smelled gas *but didn't do anything about it*... as it seems is the case with the OP, yes I guess the plant would wilt and die

Comment: There are more plumbers with the same [warnings](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-spot-signs-of-a-gas-leak-2718710) @JimmyFix-it. I would call a plumber for help immediately.